# Filenames having square brackets, NOT ignored by .gitignore?

Tags: git, regex, globbing

Editor1CurrentlyOpen[1].txt

Since regex is not effective in the .gitignore file, how can a
glob encompass filenames such as the above?

Answer (score 7):

`.gitignore` uses glob expressions on each line, so when you enter `Editor1CurrentlyOpen[1].txt` it will try to match `Editor1CurrentlyOpen1.txt`.

Add backslashes to mask the brackets in the entry:

```
Editor1CurrentlyOpen\[1\].txt
```

Comment: One  can  remove the special meaning of '?', '*' and'[' by preceding them by a backslash,
       or, in case this is part of a shell command  line,  enclosing  them  in quotes.   Between
       brackets  these characters stand for themselves.  Thus, "[[?*\]" matches the four charac-
       ters '[', '?', '*' and '\'.        Ah! found the manpages entry for that.  (http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/7/glob/) .  It had been me trying to write regexes which was both entertaining and frustrating.  Now I have to figure out how to automate the .gitignore to add those slashes.